# Sci Fi movie with a pen writing the pages of someone's life

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've done countless Google searches trying to find this movie which I saw on Netflix a couple years ago. I'm not sure of the release date of the film.

One scene I remember is where the guy is sitting in his room and the TV turns on by itself and it's a woman looking at him. She is in a parallel reality / dimension and she is also in her room when her TV turns on and he is there. At first they are scared but then they start talking to each other. She gives him her phone number and he calls her but a secretary of an office building answers the phone instead. He then looks up the number and drives all the way to the office building to find a lone pen writing the pages of someone's life (I'm not sure if it was his life or the woman's life). I think he grabs the pen and starts writing something else on it and eventually the man and woman are together in the same universe (?)

Anyway I thought it was a good movie and I was trying to recommend it to a friend but I can't find it.

Answer (score 7):

Are you thinking of [*The Frame* (2014)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2567038/)?

From the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frame_(film)):

**the guy is sitting in his room and the TV turns on by itself and it's a woman looking at him. She is in a parallel reality / dimension and she is also in her room when her TV turns on and he is there.**

> Home after collecting his pay for the recent heist, Alex stashes it in a hidden wall safe and turns on the TV to eat dinner. We see he's intently watching a television show which happens to be the scene with Sam the paramedic we just saw happen in real time. Sam is the star of the show called *Urban Hope*.
>
> Sam, home after her therapist visit, sits eating dinner in front of the TV and watches Alex's recent heist and escape with the intensity of a true fan. Alex's show is called *Thieves and Saints*.

**At first they are scared but then they start talking to each other.**

> Late one evening, as the two have their televisions on they realize that they are broadcast live from their living rooms on the others TV set. They say hello, panic, and turn off their TVs.

**He then looks up the number and drives all the way to the office building to find a lone pen writing the pages of someone's life (I'm not sure if it was his life or the woman's life). I think he grabs the pen and starts writing something else**

You may have swapped the roles in your memory; it appears that *Sam* drives to the production company.

> She springs into action remembering she had found the *Thieves and Saints* production company address and drives there only to be stopped by her Therapist who has been looking for her, fearing she is not mentally well. She runs past him into the building and to the floor of the *Thieves and Saints* writer's office. A 60's-dressed secretary sits in a small lobby staring at a phone and asks how Sam is doing. Sam goes through the only door in the room and finds herself in a vacuous room – on one side extending to infinite black and the other with spools feeding into a typing machine. She exits the other side which takes her back into the secretary's office and has the same short conversation as if on a repeating loop.
>
> Finally she summons the courage to walk toward the typing machine in the vacuous room and sees a projection image above the machine showing Alex on the floor of his apartment. The typing machine deposits the final page for “Thieves and Saints: Episode 50”. Sam picks up the script and flips through, seeing everything that had happened up to this point in his show. Sam is able to write onto the script and change Alex's fate, reviving him from death.

**eventually the man and woman are together in the same universe**

> Alex finally reaches for his violin. As he plays, the melody of her humming and his strings combine to merge their two worlds.